# Is there a way to output some stuff *only* in html?

Tags: gitbook

Basically not have it in other formats like PDF / EPUB.

I would like to put in some social / fork me kinds of links that the bottom of pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GitBook 2.0.0, you can do this using templating syntax:

```
{% if gitbook.generator == "ebook" %}
# Only for eBooks
{% else %}
# For website
{% endif %}
```

BTW: GitBook 2.0.0 will become the stable release and the default version on gitbook.com starting today.